# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data -- The underlying connection was closed Error

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

I am using **Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data** to connect to Office 365 outlook and pull emails and its attachments. This works correctly on the local development machine. My moved to a server it does not work and fails with the following error message.

```
Error: 0 : Exception occurred: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, String queryString, ViewBase view)
```

The firewall has been opened for the fully qualified domain name for outlook.office365.com from the server. The following is the network captured and having successful ack, it still seem to fail. Please let me know what might be the cause of this issue. Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely its TLS, Office365 requires that you use TLS 1.2 if the server your running it on is running an older version of the .Net framework this won't be the default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client.

Generally just doing

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

will make sure your code always uses TLS 1.2 (as longs a the framework isn't really old)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it. I was using .net framework 4.5. I would not have looked from this point of view at all. It was more than a week since I had this issue. Than k you again.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me connecting to office365 using the ExchangeService in vs 2013
It was working well until last week. without this statement.

Comment: Wow! How can I do this in PowerShell script please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databox-online/azure-stack-edge-gpu-configure-tls-settings but as a follow up note this should only be used as a temp workaround eg when tls1.3 becomes the standard this approach will cause your code to fail so you should use SchUseStrongCrypto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client so everything is done be the OS and your code can just use the best available